# OPCUA Milo- Stack-Core Failure - building phase

Tags: java, eclipse, security, opc-ua, milo

I've a problem with building Opcua Milo project for eclipse. Here the link: https://github.com/eclipse/milo .
I need to run the standalone examples for security but when I build the project (cleaning the pom and then when I go to install it I've 
[this failure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fASKL.png)

Can You give me some advice? Thank You; Sal.

EDIT 1: Error Text

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.eclipse.milo:client-examples:jar:0.2.4-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing. @ org.eclipse.milo:client-examples:[unknown-version], C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\milo-examples\client-examples\pom.xml, line 82, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.eclipse.milo:server-examples:jar:0.2.4-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing. @ org.eclipse.milo:server-examples:[unknown-version], C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\milo-examples\server-examples\pom.xml, line 76, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.eclipse.milo:standalone-examples:jar:0.2.4-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing. @ org.eclipse.milo:standalone-examples:[unknown-version], C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\milo-examples\standalone-examples\pom.xml, line 167, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.eclipse.milo:milo-examples:pom:0.2.4-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing. @ org.eclipse.milo:milo-examples:[unknown-version], C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\milo-examples\pom.xml, line 27, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.eclipse.milo:stack-examples:jar:0.2.4-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing. @ org.eclipse.milo:stack-examples:[unknown-version], C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\opc-ua-stack\stack-examples\pom.xml, line 34, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.eclipse.milo:stack-tests:jar:0.2.4-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing. @ org.eclipse.milo:stack-tests:[unknown-version], C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\opc-ua-stack\stack-tests\pom.xml, line 48, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.eclipse.milo:sdk-tests:jar:0.2.4-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing. @ org.eclipse.milo:sdk-tests:[unknown-version], C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\opc-ua-sdk\sdk-tests\pom.xml, line 55, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Eclipse Milo Build Tools                                           [jar]
[INFO] Eclipse Milo - OPC-UA (IEC 62541)                                  [pom]
[INFO] opc-ua-stack                                                       [pom]
[INFO] stack-core                                                         [jar]
[INFO] stack-client                                                       [jar]
[INFO] opc-ua-sdk                                                         [pom]
[INFO] sdk-core                                                           [jar]
[INFO] bsd-parser                                                         [pom]
[INFO] bsd-parser-core                                                    [jar]
[INFO] sdk-client                                                         [jar]
[INFO] stack-server                                                       [jar]
[INFO] sdk-server                                                         [jar]
[INFO] milo-examples                                                      [pom]
[INFO] server-examples                                                    [jar]
[INFO] client-examples                                                    [jar]
[INFO] standalone-examples                                                [jar]
[INFO] bsd-parser-gson                                                    [jar]
[INFO] stack-examples                                                     [jar]
[INFO] stack-tests                                                        [jar]
[INFO] sdk-tests                                                          [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< org.eclipse.milo:build-tools >--------------------
[INFO] Building Eclipse Milo Build Tools 0.2.4-SNAPSHOT                  [1/20]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ build-tools ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ build-tools ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ build-tools ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\build-tools\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ build-tools ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ build-tools ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ build-tools ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\build-tools\target\build-tools-0.2.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ build-tools ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\build-tools\target\build-tools-0.2.4-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\Sal\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\milo\build-tools\0.2.4-SNAPSHOT\build-tools-0.2.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\build-tools\pom.xml to C:\Users\Sal\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\milo\build-tools\0.2.4-SNAPSHOT\build-tools-0.2.4-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< org.eclipse.milo:milo >------------------------
[INFO] Building Eclipse Milo - OPC-UA (IEC 62541) 0.2.4-SNAPSHOT         [2/20]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) @ milo ---
[INFO] Starting audit...
Audit done.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ milo ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\pom.xml to C:\Users\Sal\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\milo\milo\0.2.4-SNAPSHOT\milo-0.2.4-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< org.eclipse.milo:opc-ua-stack >--------------------
[INFO] Building opc-ua-stack 0.2.4-SNAPSHOT                              [3/20]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) @ opc-ua-stack ---
[INFO] Starting audit...
Audit done.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (java-compile) @ opc-ua-stack ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:3.2.0:manifest (generate-manifest) @ opc-ua-stack ---
[WARNING] Ignoring project type pom - supportedProjectTypes = [jar, bundle]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (java-test-compile) @ opc-ua-stack ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:integration-test (default-integration-test) @ opc-ua-stack ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ opc-ua-stack ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\opc-ua-stack\pom.xml to C:\Users\Sal\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\milo\opc-ua-stack\0.2.4-SNAPSHOT\opc-ua-stack-0.2.4-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< org.eclipse.milo:stack-core >---------------------
[INFO] Building stack-core 0.2.4-SNAPSHOT                                [4/20]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) @ stack-core ---
[INFO] Starting audit...
Audit done.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ stack-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\opc-ua-stack\stack-core\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (java-compile) @ stack-core ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 381 source files to C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\opc-ua-stack\stack-core\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/Users/Sal/git/repository4prova2/miloprova2/opc-ua-stack/stack-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/stack/core/types/builtin/ExtensionObject.java: C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\opc-ua-stack\stack-core\src\main\java\org\eclipse\milo\opcua\stack\core\types\builtin\ExtensionObject.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Users/Sal/git/repository4prova2/miloprova2/opc-ua-stack/stack-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/stack/core/types/builtin/ExtensionObject.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:3.2.0:manifest (generate-manifest) @ stack-core ---
[WARNING] Manifest org.eclipse.milo:stack-core:jar:0.2.4-SNAPSHOT : Unused Import-Package instructions: [com.sun.management.*] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ stack-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (java-test-compile) @ stack-core ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 29 source files to C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\opc-ua-stack\stack-core\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ stack-core ---

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 (file:/C:/Users/Sal/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.0.36.Final/netty-common-4.0.36.Final.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
========================= init =========================
Thread[Attach Listener,5,system]
Thread[Common-Cleaner,8,InnocuousThreadGroup]
Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]
Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]
Thread[TestNGInvoker-testLifecycleClose(),5,main]
Thread[last-ditch-daemon-shutdown-thread-30sec,5,main]
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[surefire-forkedjvm-command-thread,5,main]
========================= init =========================
========================= opened =========================
Thread[Attach Listener,5,system]
Thread[Common-Cleaner,8,InnocuousThreadGroup]
Thread[FileSystemWatchService,5,main]
Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]
Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]
Thread[TestNGInvoker-testLifecycleClose(),5,main]
Thread[last-ditch-daemon-shutdown-thread-30sec,5,main]
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[surefire-forkedjvm-command-thread,5,main]
Thread[ua-certificate-directory-watcher,5,main]
========================= opened =========================
========================= closed =========================
Thread[Attach Listener,5,system]
Thread[Common-Cleaner,8,InnocuousThreadGroup]
Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]
Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]
Thread[TestNGInvoker-testLifecycleClose(),5,main]
Thread[last-ditch-daemon-shutdown-thread-30sec,5,main]
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[surefire-forkedjvm-command-thread,5,main]
========================= closed =========================
Tests run: 149, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.751 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
testInitialize(org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.BuiltinDataTypeDictionaryInitializerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.11 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.BuiltinDataTypeDictionaryInitializerTest.testInitialize(BuiltinDataTypeDictionaryInitializerTest.java:37)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  BuiltinDataTypeDictionaryInitializerTest.testInitialize:37 null

Tests run: 149, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Eclipse Milo Build Tools ........................... SUCCESS [  6.513 s]
[INFO] Eclipse Milo - OPC-UA (IEC 62541) 0.2.4-SNAPSHOT ... SUCCESS [ 10.697 s]
[INFO] opc-ua-stack ....................................... SUCCESS [ 15.518 s]
[INFO] stack-core ......................................... FAILURE [01:42 min]
[INFO] stack-client ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] opc-ua-sdk ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] sdk-core ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] bsd-parser ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] bsd-parser-core .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] sdk-client ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] stack-server ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] sdk-server ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] milo-examples ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] server-examples .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] client-examples .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] standalone-examples ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] bsd-parser-gson .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] stack-examples ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] stack-tests ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] sdk-tests 0.2.4-SNAPSHOT ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:15 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-21T14:48:57+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project stack-core: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Sal\git\repository4prova2\miloprova2\opc-ua-stack\stack-core\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :stack-core
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build with JDK 8. This is mentioned in the README but it’s easy to miss.